# Cannot change fonts in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, visual-studio-2013, settings

I used to be able to change the fonts and colors of Visual Studio 2013 by going to `Tools > Options`, then `Environment > Fonts and Colors`, and finally showing the settings for the Text Editor. However, now I cannot show the settings for the Text Editor. The first setting in the list is now the fonts and colors for the Printer.

Edit:
Here is a photo of where the setting is missing.
[image]

Comment: That is strange. I just confirmed that the first option on my environment is Text Editor and the second is Printer. Can you use the reset settings switch and see if that helps?

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it either. I remember the Text Editor setting being there before but it seems to have just disappeared.

Comment: Can I see a screen shot?

Comment: Uploaded a screen shot for you.

Comment: Please refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41208507/4652175), which can propably solve your problem. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to remove `HCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\FontAndColors\Cache`

If that will not help try to remove both `HCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\FontAndColors`
and `HCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\FontAndColors` and then run Rapair on your VS 2013 installation.

It should help.

credits goes to @leppie

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the whole operating system a while after the issue came up (along with some other problems), but if it happens again I'll be sure to try it!

Comment: Did not work for me.  I have 4 items in the "Show settings for" list and none of them are the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution!

I used regedit and and path `HCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\FontAndColors` from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26925783/1035334.

I have changed fields `FontName` & `FontPointSize` in each subdirectory of `FontAndColors` and restarted Visual Studio.

How did I find this?

I noticed when I save changes in VS, VS deleting all subdirecories of `FontAndColors` and then create its again with default values.