# Missing Text Editor font size setting in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I want to change font size in Visual Studio 2013 code editor (TextEditor setting), but this setting is missing.

[image]

However in previous VS(2012) it setting exists.

How to change font size setting in Visual Studio 2013 code editor? Ctrl+Wheel please do not offer, but is temp and bad solution for me. And why missing TextEditor option in Fonts and Colors settings?

Comment: It's present for me, although not at the top of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was found workaround. I was manually add some rows to .vssettings file (located in user/Documents and Settings/Visual Studio 2013 by default). It rows need to add to Fonts and Colors section:

```
<Category GUID="{58E96763-1D3B-4E05-B6BA-FF7115FD0B7B}" FontName="Consolas" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No"/>
<Category GUID="{75A05685-00A8-4DED-BAE5-E7A50BFA929A}" FontName="Consolas" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No"/>
<Category GUID="{E0187991-B458-4F7E-8CA9-42C9A573B56C}" FontName="Consolas" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No"/>
<Category GUID="{FF349800-EA43-46C1-8C98-878E78F46501}" FontName="Consolas" FontSize="12" CharSet="1" FontIsDefault="No"/>
```

I was copy and pasted this options from working VS2012 settings.

Answer (score -1):

It is because Microsoft SQL Server Tools were not installed. Rerun your visual studio's installer, and choose the button "modify", then check the item "Microsoft SQL Server Tools" and install it. After installing, everything should work.