# How do I change the color of .txt files in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, when I edit a text file (.txt extension), the default text editor comes up with the text in an unreadable peach color.  I've gone through every single setting in Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors to try to change it, but nothing I change under "Text Editor" makes a bit of difference.  I've also tried resetting all settings, and nothing.

Any thoughts on what is going on, and how I can reset the colors for editing .txt files to something sane?

[image: Unreadable peachy]

Comment: Just did what you suggested - changed font color for plain text in Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors. Worked fine for me. Simple suggestion - how about restarting VS? Also, this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830318/cannot-change-fonts-in-visual-studio-2013?rq=1

Comment: Been going on for months, so rebooting isn't the issue.  Also seemed to have ported when I installed VS2013 - it was happening in VS2012 previously.  I'll try the registry settings in the link & report back